# How to save images on ftp server or sql db?

Tags: sql, web-applications, ftp

For every row which represents clients data (name, phone etc) need to save also 3 images. Is it better saving images to ftp or in sql db? 
Images will be shown in bootstrap carousel.
(I'll use asp5-mvc6 with ms sql db)

Comment: what did you want to say here? "Is it better saving images to DB or in sql db?"

Comment: I fixed it. when I say ftp I mean into root directory where is the app. not extra ftp server only for saving images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that if you have a very good infraestructure, save in the DB is better, and here is why I think that:

1. You can access it in the same way that your other data
2. No extra setups for serving the media
3. If you have multiple servers, your sync is done with the DB

But if you have a small app, with small server, putting the media in a folder and keep in the db a reference to the file is not the end of world, but if you have more than one server, remember you will have to replicate the file in the other servers as well.

I would say you should try both ways before making a decision.

Comment: So better with ftp, Its a small app, Thank you